# gcutil is not woking with OS X 10.9

Tags: ssh, osx-mavericks, google-compute-engine, gcutil

INFO: Running command line: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 ${USER}@${IP} --
./sshBecalos: line 1:  1632 Killed: 9               gcutil --service_version="xxxx" --project="xxx" ssh --zone="us-central1-a" "xxx"

Comment: Could you reformat your post to make it a bit easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and we are working on getting a fix out ASAP.

In the meantime, you can run the command output in the INFO line.

We are tracking this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=36).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=36) linked above, please download the latest version of [gcutil](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/) (1.10.0) to resolve.